# Change images on multiple drop downs. One Javascript(update)

Tags: javascript, html, image, drop-down-menu, onchange

So Im trying to make a chart with images that pop up in each cell of the table based on a drop down selection.
Ive been having trouble because there's multiple selections and I can't seem to get one javascript function to work for all the drop downs(all have the same options and images available)

Here is what I have now

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function swapImage(){
    var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
    var dropd = document.getElementById("dlist");
    image.src = dropd.value;        
};

</script><script>

function swap2twinleaf(){
    var image = document.getElementById("twinleaf2swap");
    var dropd = document.getElementById("dlist2");
    image.src = dropd.value;        
};

</script>
```

and the html I have

```
<img id="imageToSwap" alt="sprite" src="Pokemon%20DW%20Sprites/387.png">

<select id="dlist" onChange="swapImage()">
<option value="C:\Users\Gaia Soul\Desktop\Pokemon DW Spirites - 20170920T221714Z-001\Pokemon DW Spirites\387.png">Turtwig</option>
<option value="C:\Users\Gaia Soul\Desktop\Pokemon DW Spirites - 20170920T221714Z-001\Pokemon DW Spirites\390.png">Piplup</option>
<option value="C:\Users\Gaia Soul\Desktop\Pokemon DW Spirites - 20170920T221714Z-001\Pokemon DW Spirites\393.png">Chimchar</option>
</select>


</td><td>

<img id="twinleaf2swap" alt="sprite" src="Pokemon%20DW%20Sprites/387.png">
<select id="dlist2" onChange="swap2twinleaf()">
<option value="C:\Users\Gaia Soul\Desktop\Pokemon DW Spirites - 20170920T221714Z-001\Pokemon DW Spirites\387.png">Turtwig</option>
<option value="C:\Users\Gaia Soul\Desktop\Pokemon DW Spirites - 20170920T221714Z-001\Pokemon DW Spirites\393.png">Piplup</option>
<option value="C:\Users\Gaia Soul\Desktop\Pokemon DW Spirites - 20170920T221714Z-001\Pokemon DW Spirites\390.png">Chimchar</option>
</select>
```

The first one works, but the second one never seems to do anything.
I do have quite a large table, so I would like to keep the javascript to one function for all of them.

Comment: Also I've been putting the javascript in the <head> tag if that's fine

Comment: You'll need to have unique ID's for your `img` elements - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id.

Comment: Then you can pass the unique `ID` to your `swapImage` function call bound to `onChange`. Rather than hard-coding the `ID` in `document.getElementById("imageToSwap")`, you can use the passed in `ID` to get the correct `img` element.

Answer (score 0):

you have duplicate id's for both select elements.

basically when you call this

```
var dropd = document.getElementById("dlist");
```

You are going to get the first element it encounters so you will ALWAYS get the value from the top dropdown box

you can pass the value in the onchange event and go from there

```
<select onChange="swapImage(this)">
```

and then use the same function still just instead of grabbing the value from the DOM element you are passing it in as an argument.

```
function swapImage(sel){
    //get the value selected in the dropdown box
    var value = sel.value; 
};
```

`

Comment: so I can use the same function if I change the java to    function swapImage(sel)

Comment: yes, because instead of grabbing the value of the dom element, it passes it into the function.

think pushing the value instead of pulling it from inside the function